# Problem with Laravel Sanctum SPA (multi auth) Authentication with Vue JS returning 'Not Authorized'

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

My Laravel project comprises of 3 separate users: admin, vendors and customers. The project is a mixture of server-side rendering with Vue components embedded here and there.

My guards is as follows

```
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'vendor-api' => [
            'driver' => 'sanctum',
            'provider' => 'vendors',
        ],
        'admin-api' => [
            'driver' => 'sanctum',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
        'customer-api' => [
            'driver' => 'sanctum',
            'provider' => 'customers',
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],

        'vendor' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'vendors',
        ],

        'customer' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'customers',
        ],
    ],
```

All my user models have the HasApiToken trait within them and I have done all the necessary setup as stipulated in the documentation.

When a vendor is logging in, this is the method that is run, first I do a get to the sanctum route then a post request to log in which returns the $vendor alongside it's token.

```
            axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => { //first get call as stated in the documentations
                console.log(response)
                axios.post(this.route('api.vendors.login'), { //then a post call to a log in the user 
                    email: this.email,
                    password: this.password
                }).then(response => {
                    const token = response.data.token
                    axios.get(this.route('api.vendors.profile.show', 1))
                        .then(async (response) => {
                            console.log(response.data, "This is the vendor from the guarded api data");
                            this.$refs.loginForm.submit(); //this actually logs the user in using the web guard setup
                        })
                        .catch(function (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        });

                })
            });
```

Now, I expect that the log in flow would have set the necessary token cookies in the browser (which it does as I can see it) and that a subsequent call to the API will be successful, it however returns as **Unauthorized**

However, when I used the token that was returned for example in Postman, I get a reply from the API and also in axios when the token is included in the header, the API works well. It's the Sanctum cookie/session based authorization that doesn't seem to be working.

My routes in the API are protected as follows as thus

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:vendor-api'], function () {
        Route::resource('/profile', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\Vendors\ProfileController', ['as' => 'api.vendors']);

    });
```

I checked the headers for the unauthorized call and can see that the X_XRSF token is included.
My SESSION_DRIVER has been set to cookie.
My sanctum config has been set to local host

```
    'stateful' => explode(',', env(
        'SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS',
        'localhost,localhost:3002,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8008,::1,' . parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST)
    )),

    'middleware' => [
        'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to the js side.

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

as specified here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#cors-and-cookies